# Animate Path in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg-animate

Is there any possiblity to "Fly-In" an svgpath in IE 11?

Like

```
@keyframes fadeInP {
    from
    {
        stroke-dashoffset:1000;
    }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.animate
{
 animation: fadeInP 10s linear infinite;
}
```

For

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
 <path stroke-width='8' class = "animate" fill='none' stroke="#ffffff" d="M 0,0 C 100,10 200,80 300,15 " />
</svg>
```

This works in FF, but cant find any solution in the web to do soemthing similar in IE.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sadly, I believe the only solution is to use JS and update the offset for every frame.

Animating SVG with CSS doesn't work in IE and neither do SMIL animations.

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/CxkHm)

### **JS**:

```
var p = document.querySelector('.animate'), 
    offset = 1000;

var offsetMe = function() {
  if(offset < 0) offset = 1000;
  p.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
  offset--;
  
  requestAnimationFrame(offsetMe);
}

offsetMe();
```

**Update** 26th of January 2015: [the IE team is working on this](https://twitter.com/jacobrossi/status/560200238627975168).

**Update #2** Edge now supports this, *though only with units* (that is `stroke-dashoffset: 1000;` won't work, but `stroke-dashoffset: 1000px;` will).

Comment: +1 Wonderful solution. Thanks for sharing. I agree with the TO that this is very difficult to google. This is the first easy & working solution for IE i have seen on the web.

Comment: @BudBrot I've submitted an issue about this https://github.com/InternetExplorer/Status.IE/issues/117

Comment: On (the Microsoft developers website)[https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/csstransitionsforsvgelements/] it says it is supported since build 10240. Do you know what version of Edge that is? Or is it supported for all Edge versions?